# PHP Login authentication failed

Tags: php, ftp

I've used this to login in a ftp account for about 4 years:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('server') or die ("ERROR");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user', 'pass');
```

Last days it wont work. No changes in account, server, or PHP version. I can access the same account in a FTP client. In the site, will return: `Warning: ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Login authentication failed in /home/.....`

Search in documentation and everything seems ok.

Comment: something must have changed. Errors like this won't appear for no reason.

Comment: Indeed. But I'm out of ideas. Pretty sure it's not the code. The adms says nothing changed.

Comment: have you tried logging in with a normal ftp client? Since it does say authentication failed, you ARE connecting, just failing to log in. e.g. your account's been disabled.

Comment: Could be changes to the server on their end - e.g. A firewall stopping your server connecting, a change of IP address, a change in ftp details.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have providied your password in single quote, if your password contains any $ symbol and if you have declared ur password in double quotes then the characters after the $ symbol are considered as php variable. even i was facing this issue and it was solved just by changing the quotes.